# Populate table in ascending order

Tags: javascript, php

I use the code below to populate a very large table and the table populates in descending order. Sometimes, the full table does not show and the new contents down will not appear. I want this table to populate in ascending order since what i require is the most recent contents.
Thanks for your help.

```
<?php
echo "<table style='border: solid 1px black;'>";
echo "<tr><th>mydate</th><th>mball14</th><th>mball14a</th><th>mball15</th>
<th>mball15a</th><th>mball16</th><th>mball16a</th><th>mball17</th>        
<th>mball17a</th><th>mball18</th><th>mball18a</th><th>mball19</th>
<th>mball19a</th><th>mball20</th><th>mball20a</th></tr>";

class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator {
 function __construct($it) {
     parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY);
 }

 function current() {
     return "<td style='width: 150px; border: 1px solid black;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
 }

 function beginChildren() {
     echo "<tr>";
 }

 function endChildren() {
     echo "</tr>" . "\n";
 }
}

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "***";
$password = "***";
$dbname = "***";

try {
 $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
 $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT mydate, mball14, mball14a, mball15, mball15a, mball16, mball16a, mball17, mball17a, mball18, mball18a, mball19, mball19a, mball20, mball20a FROM manager");
 $stmt->execute();

 // set the resulting array to associative
 $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) {
     echo $v;
 }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
 echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Add an `ORDER BY` clause to your SQL query?

Comment: Urmmm add to the query `ORDER BY mydate` or replace `mydate` with whichever column you want to sort on

Comment: SO is not here to replace looking in the manual, Or a simple GOOGLE search

Comment: Thanks to you all. `ORDER BY` has done it.

Comment: Why the `java` tag for a PHP question?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT mydate, mball14, mball14a, mball15, mball15a, mball16, mball16a, mball17, mball17a, mball18, mball18a, mball19, mball19a, mball20, mball20a FROM manager");
```

To

```
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT mydate, mball14, mball14a, mball15, mball15a, mball16, mball16a, mball17, mball17a, mball18, mball18a, mball19, mball19a, mball20, mball20a FROM manager ORDER BY mydate DESC");
```

This will take the dates, and put the newest on the top